# How to parse 'askopenfilename' file pathway into another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tkinter

I am trying to create an image segmentation application with Python and Tkinter. I am having trouble taking the file pathway obtained through `filedialog.askopenfilename` (user uploads from file), and parsing the image pathway through the image segmentation function by the click of another button on the Tkinter GUI.

Because I wanted to have a button to collect the file pathway, I created a function to bind to the button but the image segmentation function wasn't able to get the pathway variable within the file pathway function. So I create global variables, however, the segmentation function wasn't able to read `string` or `NoneType` objects. Also, I tried creating a `class` for all this but it did not work.

Here are the two functions (`decode_segmap` is needed for segmentation function):

```
# Define the helper function
def decode_segmap(image, nc=21):

  label_colors = np.array([(0, 0, 0),  # 0=background
               # 1=aeroplane, 2=bicycle, 3=bird, 4=boat, 5=bottle
               (128, 0, 0), (0, 128, 0), (128, 128, 0), (0, 0, 128), (128, 0, 128),
               # 6=bus, 7=car, 8=cat, 9=chair, 10=cow
               (0, 128, 128), (128, 128, 128), (64, 0, 0), (192, 0, 0), (64, 128, 0),
               # 11=dining table, 12=dog, 13=horse, 14=motorbike, 15=person
               (192, 128, 0), (64, 0, 128), (192, 0, 128), (64, 128, 128), (192, 128, 128),
               # 16=potted plant, 17=sheep, 18=sofa, 19=train, 20=tv/monitor
               (0, 64, 0), (128, 64, 0), (0, 192, 0), (128, 192, 0), (0, 64, 128)])

  r = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
  g = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
  b = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)

  for l in range(0, nc):
    idx = image == l
    r[idx] = label_colors[l, 0]
    g[idx] = label_colors[l, 1]
    b[idx] = label_colors[l, 2]

  rgb = np.stack([r, g, b], axis=2)
  return rgb

def segment(net, path):
  img = Image.open(path)
  plt.imshow(img); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()
  # Comment the Resize and CenterCrop for better inference results
  trf = T.Compose([T.Resize(256), 
                   T.CenterCrop(224), 
                   T.ToTensor(), 
                   T.Normalize(mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                               std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
  inp = trf(img).unsqueeze(0)
  out = net(inp)['out']
  om = torch.argmax(out.squeeze(), dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy()
  rgb = decode_segmap(om)
  plt.imshow(rgb); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()

def open_img():
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Downloads',title='Select Photo', filetypes=(('JPEG files', '*.jpg'),('PNG files', '*.png')))
    img = Image.open(path)
    plt.imshow(img); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()
```

The Tkinter code (two frames, one for buttons, other for previewing image):
As you may see, the segment function takes two parameters, the `fcn` is the neural network and is a "global" variable in the file, however the path parameter cannot be obtained as the variable lies in another function bind to a button.

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")

btn_frame = Frame(window, width=500, height=100)
btn_frame.pack(side="top", expand=True, fill="both")
bottom_frame = Frame(window, width=500, height=200)
bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", expand=True, fill="both")

btn1 = Button(btn_frame, text="Open", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2", command=open_img)
btn1.pack(side="left")
btn2 = Button(btn_frame, text="Segment", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2", command=segment(net=fcn, path=path))
btn2.pack(side="left")
btn3 = Button(btn_frame, text="Save", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2")
btn3.pack(side="left")

window.mainloop()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You still use ***`command=segment(net=fcn, path=path)`***, this is already answerd in your previous same question: [python-tkinter-multiple-buttons-wont-display-in-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61982445)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: try this? `btn2 = Button(btn_frame, text="Segment", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2", command=lambda: segment(net=fcn, path=path))`

Comment: @stovfl Thank you, I ended up adding your suggestion to the new code based on the answer below.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks, the addition of `lambda` actually made the segment button initiate, however, I did get an `OMP: Error #15`. I explain about it below. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @CoolCloud It turns out the error had something to do with MacOS and I got it solved. I finally got the app to run properly.

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to solve this but first of all:

`command=function()` e.g. will set the return value of function as the "command" because the function will get directly executed. In your example it should throw an error since path does not seem to be defined yet.

Anyway here are 2 "workarounds":

1. You could create a variable called path, put the statement `global path` at the beginning of your `open_img`-functionto be able to set path globally. Then you'd be able to remove the "path" parameter from your `segment`-function while still reading the contents of the path variable.
2. Create a class and save path as class field `self.path` or something similar so you can use it in `segment` too.

Here is how I'd have done it:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL.ImageTk import Image, PhotoImage
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from ? import T

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self)
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x300")

        self.path = ''

        btn_frame = Frame(self, width=500, height=100)
        btn_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        btn_frame.pack_propagate(False) #otherwise your width and height options would be useless
        bottom_frame = Frame(self, width=500, height=200)
        bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        btn1 = Button(btn_frame, text="Open", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2", command=self.open_img)
        btn1.pack(side=LEFT)
        btn2 = Button(btn_frame, text="Segment", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2", command=self.segment)
        #command=segment(net=fcn, path=path) would instantly execute the command but there is no path variable
        btn2.pack(side=LEFT)
        btn3 = Button(btn_frame, text="Save", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2")
        btn3.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.image_label = Label(bottom_frame)
        self.image_label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.mainloop()
    def decode_segmap(image, nc=21):

        label_colors = np.array([(0, 0, 0),  # 0=background
                                 # 1=aeroplane, 2=bicycle, 3=bird, 4=boat, 5=bottle
                                 (128, 0, 0), (0, 128, 0), (128, 128, 0), (0, 0, 128), (128, 0, 128),
                                 # 6=bus, 7=car, 8=cat, 9=chair, 10=cow
                                 (0, 128, 128), (128, 128, 128), (64, 0, 0), (192, 0, 0), (64, 128, 0),
                                 # 11=dining table, 12=dog, 13=horse, 14=motorbike, 15=person
                                 (192, 128, 0), (64, 0, 128), (192, 0, 128), (64, 128, 128), (192, 128, 128),
                                 # 16=potted plant, 17=sheep, 18=sofa, 19=train, 20=tv/monitor
                                 (0, 64, 0), (128, 64, 0), (0, 192, 0), (128, 192, 0), (0, 64, 128)])

        r = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
        g = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
        b = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)

        for l in range(0, nc):
            idx = image == l
            r[idx] = label_colors[l, 0]
            g[idx] = label_colors[l, 1]
            b[idx] = label_colors[l, 2]

        rgb = np.stack([r, g, b], axis=2)
        return rgb

    def segment(self, net):
        #if an image is chosen path will be any other than ''
        if path: img = Image.open(self.path)
        else: return
        plt.imshow(img); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()
        # Comment the Resize and CenterCrop for better inference results
        trf = T.Compose([T.Resize(256), 
                         T.CenterCrop(224), 
                         T.ToTensor(), 
                         T.Normalize(mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                                     std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
        inp = trf(img).unsqueeze(0)
        out = net(inp)['out']
        om = torch.argmax(out.squeeze(), dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy()
        rgb = decode_segmap(om)
        plt.imshow(rgb); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()

    def open_img(self):
        path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Downloads',title='Select Photo', filetypes=(('JPEG files', '*.jpg'),('PNG files', '*.png')))
        if path:
            self.path = path
            img = PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
            #img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=path) should work too but then you'll need to remove the import of PILs PhotoImage
            self.image_label.img = img #keep a reference to the image object
            self.image_label.config(image=img)
            #plt.imshow(img); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was thinking of doing a class but did not entirely know how to. I was getting a `path` undefined when calling the segment function so I added the `path` parameter to the function and changed the button binding to `command=lambda: self.segment(net=fcn, path=self.path))`. I added lambda from suggestions of comments above due to the segment button not doing anything when running the program. The entire program ended up running quite well, however, I got his error: `OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized`.

Comment: The segment button worked as it displayed the preview of the chosen image, however it never showed the segmented image as a `matplotlib` plot and upon closing the preview the error stated above showed. Thanks again for helping out and providing the code, it's very appreciated.

Comment: Never mind, it got solved, apparently it is a MacOS problem.